# Nothing is output in python recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, global-variables, iterable

- List item

I'm working on a code that calculates the 'distance' between two configurations of a Flip Cube, The distance between two configurations x and y is the minimum number of steps required to go from x to y, or conversely.

To make that I've created a simpler version that makes something different, this code takes two integer numbers **ci** and **cf**. with **ci** returns an iterable called **main_level** through the generator called **multi**, then, it iterates through it searching for the parameter **cf**, whenever **cf** is not in **main_level** the variable **steps** is increased by 1 and for each element in **main_level** we repeat the same process done for **ci**. Finally, when **cii==cf** the program ends and returns the **steps** variable, which counts the number of "levels"  that we have to go down to find the given parameter **cf**. This code doesn't have any practical purpose is just a base for the problem I mentioned above.

If  I call the **distance(ci, cf)** function with ci=5, the first  two levels are:

**{0,3,6,9,12}**   <--  first level (steps  is initialized with  1)
if **cf** is any of the  numbers in the set, the program should end and return steps=**1**,
if **cf** is not in that set, the  programs form the second level:
**{15,18,21,24,27,30,33}** and search **cf**, if **cf** is there, the program ends and should return  steps=**2**, if not, it forms the third level, and so on. But there is a problem, actually, when I call the distance function with **ci**=5 and **cf**= any natural number, and print its value, anything is output,  only for **cf**=0, it outputs step=**1**. I don't really know what's going on. I would appreciate your help.

Here is the code:

```
#Base solution to FlipCube problem

def multi(par):
   for i in range(par):
     yield i*3    

steps=1 

def distance(ci,cf):
    main_level =set(multi(ci))
    global steps  

    def check_main_level(cf):
        global  steps 
        nonlocal  main_level
        
        def lower_level(config_list):
            sett=set()
            for i in config_list:
               sett.update(q for q in multi(i) if q not in config_list)
            nonlocal  main_level
            main_level=sett
            check_main_level(cf)  

        for i in main_level:
            if i==cf:
                break
            else:
                steps+=1
                lower_level(main_level)
    check_main_level(cf)              
    return steps  
    
#testing
e=  distance(5,0)
print(e)# prints 1, very good
e2=  distance(5,9)
print(e2)# should print  1, but doesn't print anything :(
e3=  distance(5,27)
print(e3)# should print  2, but doesn't print anything :(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program does not terminate recursion under all circumstances. The culprit seems to be the `for` loop in `check_main_level`. Change the code after your definition of `lower_level` to:

```
# code portion of check_main_level
        if cf > max(main_level):
            steps+=1
            lower_level(main_level)
# end of code portion check_main_level (replacing for-loop)
```

Answer (score -1):

you have an infinity loop, that's why nothing is printed.

You can see it easyly by adding a print :

```
for i in config_list:
               print(i)
               sett=set()
               sett.update(q for q in list(multi(i)) if q not in config_list)
```